# How to enable/disable 2nd dropdownlist value based on the selection of the previous dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have 2 dropdowns. On selection of the first dropdown the value related to it show be enabled or get highlighted and rest other options should be in disabled in the second dropdown. Both the dropdowns are multiselect and are array of objects.

I am able to append the conditional value in the second dropdown but rest other options are getting hide.I want all options to be visible and teh one selcted should be enabled/highlighted.

var firstVal = [

```
{ id: 1, value: 'foo1' },
{ id: 2, value: 'foo2' },
{ id: 3, value: 'foo3' },
```

]
var secondVal = [

```
{ id: 1, value: 'foo11' },
{ id: 2, value: 'foo21' },
{ id: 2, value: 'foo22' },
{ id: 3, value: 'foo31' },
{ id: 3, value: 'foo32' },
```

]

```
$('#rewardType').change(function (){
var firstSelcted = $(this).val();if (firstSelcted && firstSelcted.length > 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < firstSelcted.length; j++) {                
            var filtered = secondVal.filter( function(myArr){
                 return myArr.id == firstSelcted[j];
        });for (var k = 0; k < filtered.length; k++) {
            $('#rewardTypes').append('<option value="' + filtered[k].value + '">' + filtered[k].value + '</option>');                   
            }
            $('this').css('background-color','red');
            $('#rewardTypes').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
```

If I select foo2 in first dropdown then in 2nd dropdown it should get highlighted or enabled foo21,foo22. And rest others should be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below approach where you can populate list using json array and on change event of first list you can enable or disable the second list options

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var firstVal = [
{ id: 1, value: 'foo1' },
{ id: 2, value: 'foo2' },
{ id: 3, value: 'foo3' },
] ;
var secondVal = [
{ id: 1, value: 'foo11' },
{ id: 2, value: 'foo21' },
{ id: 2, value: 'foo22' },
{ id: 3, value: 'foo31' },
{ id: 3, value: 'foo32' },  
]
var $firstList = $('#rewardType');
var $secondList = $('#rewardTypes');
$.each(firstVal, function(key,val){
  $firstList.append('<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val.value + '</option>');
});
$.each(secondVal, function(key,val){
  $secondList.append('<option disabled value="' + val.id + '">' + val.value + '</option>');
});
$firstList.change(function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   //console.log(value);
   $secondList.val("");
   $secondList.find('option').each(function(){
      var optVal = $(this).attr('value');
      //console.log("option " + optVal);
      if(value.indexOf(optVal)>=0) {
         $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
      } else {
         $(this).attr('disabled',true);
      }
   });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="rewardType" multiple="true"><option value=""></option></select>
<select id="rewardTypes" multiple="true"><option value=""></option></select>
```

Comment: Please explain if(value.indexOf(optVal)>=0) of the code.

Comment: value.indexOf(optVal)>=0 : value contains array of selected values from first dropdown and it checks the value of options in second dropdown to make it enable or disable. If indexOf value is >=0 then it contains the values and enables the option.

Answer (score 0):

First code block is for HTML and second code block is JQuery
try this:

```
<select id='firstval' onchange="witness();">
    <option selected></option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
</select>

<select id='secondval'>
    <option selected></option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
</select>

function witness(){
    $("#secondval option").each(function(){
        if($("#firstval option:selected").val() == $(this).val())
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        else
            $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    });
}
```